# Itertools.chain.from_iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

Can anyone explain to me, what exactly this code snippet is doing?

```
chained_country_list = set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(country_and_countrycodes)) & set(all_countries)
```

I know it runs two lists against each other, ending up with a set of unique values, that exists in both the lists it compares.

But how it does it, and whats happening under the hood, confuses me.

Would be a huge help if someone could share some light on the issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's break down each significant element of the code:

**itertools.chain.from_iterable:**

Basically, this is used to flatten a nested list, like this:

```
l = [[0], [1, 2], [2], [3, 6], [4], [5, 10]]
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l))
```

**Output:**

```
[0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 6, 4, 5, 10]
```

**`&` operator between two sets:**

Consider the follow example of sets a and b.

```
a = {1, 2, 3}
b = {2, 3, 4}
a & b
```

**Output:**

```
{2, 3}
```

So basically it gets the common elements between two sets. Here they're 2 and 3.

**The code as a whole:**

Let's say:

```
country_and_countrycodes = [('United States', 'US'), ('China', 'CH')]
all_countries = ['United States', 'Mongolia', 'Togo']
```

Now, the first part is:

```
set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(country_and_countrycodes))
```

which gives us:

```
{'CH', 'China', 'US', 'United States'}
```

So, it just gets us a flat set from the tuples.

Then, the second part is:

```
set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(country_and_countrycodes)) & set(all_countries)
```

which gives us:

```
{'United States'}
```

Basically, what we did was:

```
{'CH', 'China', 'US', 'United States'} & {'United States', 'Mongolia', 'Togo'}
```

Since the only common element here is `'United States'`, that's what we got as the output.

Answer (score 5):

It's hard to tell what does your code do without knowing the type and value of the objects passed to the functions. However, the function `chain.from_iterable` tries to create a flattened iterable off of `country_and_countrycodes` which presumably should be a nested iterables like a nested list. At next step the `set` function creates a set from the flattened result in order to be and-able with `set(all_countries)`.

Now as a more Pythonic alternative to the following part:

```
set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(country_and_countrycodes))
```

You could just pass the iterables to `set().union()` function in order to create a union set of unique items at once.

Example:

```
In [2]: set().union(*[[1, 3], [5, 6], [3, 5]])
Out[2]: {1, 3, 5, 6}
```

So, you can change that code to the following:

```
set().union(*country_and_countrycodes) & set(all_countries)
# Or
# set().union(*country_and_countrycodes).intersection(all_countries)
```