# Shuffling an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have this array:

```
arr=[[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]
```

I would like the 1's to be distributed in randomly in second, third and first row.

For example, a wanted result would be:

```
arr=[[1,1,0],[0,0,0],[0,1,0] or arr=[[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,0]
```

However, using

```
np.random.shuffle(arr)
```

results in shuffling the rows and not the elements.

Comment: Can you rotate the array of arrays and then shuffle the, now, columns, then rotate back again?

Comment: make it a (9,1) shuffle make it (3,3) again

Answer (score 4):

Extending my comment with an example, leveraging [itertools.chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775024/itertools-chain-from-iterable) and [random.shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976882/shuffling-a-list-of-objects) - as Lucas already provided the numpy solution:

```
import random
from itertools import chain 

arr=[[1,1,0],[0,0,0],[0,1,0]]    

# make it a 1-dim list
chained = list(chain.from_iterable(arr))

# shuffle it 
random.shuffle(chained)

# repartition it again
new = [chained[i:i+3] for i in range(0,9,3)]

print(new)
```

Outputs (several tries):

```
[[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0]]

[[1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

[[0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1]]

[[0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1]]

[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Beat me to the answer. That being said `[chained[i:i+3] for i in range(0,9,3)]` can be written shorter as `[chained[i::3] for i in range(3)]`. Also `list(chain.from_iterable(arr))` could just be `list(chain(*arr))`

Comment: I believe your solution is more pythonic than mine

Answer (score 2):

You could create an extended list, shuffle it then group it again, like this:

```
import numpy as np

arr=[[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]

extended_array = []
for array in arr:
    extended_array.extend(array)

np.random.shuffle(extended_array)

arr = list(zip(*[iter(extended_array)] * 3))

print(arr)
```

Possible output:

```
[(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1)]
```

Comment: Is this result allowed, with two ones in the last column?

Comment: @quamrana I believe so, like in his example in the question.

Answer (score 2):

How about make an ndarray, flatten, shuffle, and reshape:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])
flat = np.array(arr.flat)

np.random.shuffle(flat)

result_array = flat.reshape(arr.shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could deconstruct your array, shuffle it and construct it back

```
import numpy as np

arr=[[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]

flat_arr = [item for sublist in arr for item in sublist]

np.random.shuffle(flat_arr)

arr=np.array(flat_arr)

np.split(arr,3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```py
import numpy as np

arr = [[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]

np.random.permutation(np.array(arr).reshape(1, 9)[0]).reshape(3, 3).tolist()
```

Output (yours may be different, because randomness):

```py
[[0, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
```

Explanation:

- `np.array(x)` converts the list x into a numpy array.
- `reshape(1, 9)` takes `[[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0]]` and returns [[`1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]`, so we get its first element (the entire sublist) with `[0]`.
- `np.random.permutation(x)` takes a list `x` and returns a random shuffled copy.

  - We use this instead of the seemingly more obvious `np.random.shuffle(x)`, which is destructive and shuffles the list in place instead of returning a copy.
- `reshape(3, 3)` takes our `(1, 9)` list and turns it back into a `(3, 3)`
- Finally, `tolist()` turns our numpy array back into a Python list.